# Redirect login component in .htaccess Joomla -> Community Builder

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, joomla

I'm building a website with Joomla and Community builder.

What I need help with is redirecting to specific page when user is not logged in!

After pressing module link outside Joomla:

```
index.php?option=com_jevents&task=icalrepeat.detail&evid=16&Itemid=490&year=2011&month=11&day=17&title=personalefest-jysk&uid=3f380241e99b5db330b8e05f8920340a&login=1
```

Joomla redirecs to this: `index.php/component/users/?view=login`

Where I really want to go to this: `/index.php/component/comprofiler/login` (which is CB component's login view)

They go through some interesting things here
[Issuing a redirect from a Joomla module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8048563/issuing-a-redirect-from-a-joomla-module)
and here
[RewriteRule to redirect with url that got parameters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4951898/rewriterule-to-redirect-with-url-that-got-parameters)

But I'm not able to fully understand how I make the right changes.

Comment: Have you read the Community Builder documentation?  Also, I see a topic on the Community Builder forum, [Change default login redirect](http://www.joomlapolis.com/forum/145-community-builder/159771-change-default-login-redirect), which has some suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

The first link you provided has the answer:

You create a public article which you can call "dispatcher.php" and it will have the following code:

```
<?php
$user =& JFactory::getUser();
    include_once JPATH_COMPONENT . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . "controller.php"; // assuming com_content

if (!$user->id) { //user is not logged in
    $contentController = new ContentController();
    $link = JRoute::_("/index.php/component/comprofiler/login");
    $contentController->setRedirect($link);
    return;
} else { //the user is logged in
    $contentController = new ContentController();
    $link = JRoute::_("/index.php?option=com_jevents&task=icalrepeat.detail&evid=16&Itemid=490&year=2011&month=11&day=17&title=personalefest-jysk&uid=3f380241e99b5db330b8e05f8920340a&login=1");
    $contentController->setRedirect($link);
    return;
}
?>
```

Instead of providing a link to your article - you provide a link to dispatcher.php which will "decide" where to redirect the user (to your page - if the user is logged in - else to the other login page)

You might have to debug it - since I don't have time to test it myself.
Good luck!